# bxslider sometimes shows properly when page refreshed never on initial load

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

The slider does not load properly on the first load.At random times it will work properly on first load but at other times it doesn't. Only the bullet shows up in the wrong position on the page. When you reload then everything snaps into place properly. And I have also noticed with other sites I have built the CSS loads improperly sometimes until the page is reloaded. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      auto: true,
      autoStart:true,
      captions:true,
      preloadImages: 'none'
      });

    });

</script>



<div style="float:left !important" ><ul class="bxslider">
  <li><a href="http://templesschoolofkarate.com/contact.php"><img alt="Sign up today for two free classes" src= "http://templesschoolofkarate.com/res/slide/slide1.jpg"  /></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://templesschoolofkarate.com/programs.php"><img alt="we are rate #1" src="http://templesschoolofkarate.com/res/slide/slide2.jpg"  /></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://templesschoolofkarate.com/programs-weapons.php"><img alt="ask about our weapons program" src="http://templesschoolofkarate.com/res/slide/slide3.jpg"  /></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://templesschoolofkarate.com/programs-kids.php"><img alt="kids learn more than just kicking and punching" src="http://templesschoolofkarate.com/res/slide/slide4.jpg" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Link to website http://templesschoolofkarate.com

Comment: Can you post only the code regarding the slider part, not all of it ?

Comment: are you checking in IE...?? because in moz, its loading just fine!! :)

Comment: It happens at random times sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't

Comment: @OshaneBaker : I assume then its some environment issue, not code...!! :)

Comment: Did your problem solve? I have a problem like this now. @Oshane Baker

Comment: @OshaneBaker : I am facing this issue? Can you please tell me whether you resolved it or not?

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same issue and I think I've tracked down the effect - as you can see below, the wrapper element will sometimes set itself a height of 0px.

[image]

Not 100% sure, but for me I think it was the page refreshing mid-transition. I hadn't explicitly set `startSlide` and even though it says in the docs the default is 0, that wasn't working.

I've included `startSlide:0` in my initialisation and that seems to have fixed the issue for me.